# AVFoundation library: Sound Will Not Play

Tags: cocoa

Working on my second app...

Have buttons going to individual images and when app moves to new image. I want to play sound, but its not working...

in .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

#import "SoundController.h"

@interface BoatController : UIViewController {

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *Cruise_Ship;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *Speed_Boat;

@end
```

in .m file:

```
#import "BoatController.h"

@implementation BoatController

@synthesize Cruise_Ship;

@synthesize Speed_Boat;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

}

-(void)View01
{
    UIView * containingView = Cruise_Ship;
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [containingView addSubview:Cruise_Ship];
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"boathorn01",CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}

-(void)View2
{
    UIView * containingView = Speed_Boat.superview;
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [containingView addSubview:Speed_Boat];    
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"nautical010",CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);    
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}

@end
```

Any ideas?  Trying to move from a controller via buttons to various pictures.  Navigation works, but sounds do not play.

Comment: Retagged because this is not an XCode issue. Your question relates to the Cocoa framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
system("afplay path")
```